# Requirement of invoking the clear() function on map variable in C++

Tags: c++, stl

By default the program runs fine, but should I explicitly invoke h.clear() in the main(), or is clear() always invoked in case of declaration of a global map variable?

```
map <int , long long> h;
long long f(int n)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
int main()
{
    long long int t,n,x;
//Should I explicitly invoke h.clear() here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is really just this, then the map will be empty.

It could be non-empty in more exotic cases like

```
map <int , long long> h;

int fetchSomeVar()
{
  h[ 0 ] = 0;
  return 0;
}

int someVar = fetchSomeVar();


int main()
{
  //...
}
```

where fetchSomeVar will be called before main and happens to modify the map, but such constructs should be avoided.

Comment: So, if the variable is declared within say : main(), i.e. when it is non-global, is it also empty at the creation time?

Comment: yes because then it is not a global variable anymore, so it's only initialized when it comes into scope

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the information. I really appreciate your help.
Could you also suggest some reference so that look-up for such info might be done by myself?

Comment: I guess the documentation of std::map (for instance http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) might be a good starting point. Another way that will learn you more: write the code, compile it, then run it under the debugger step by step so you can inspect the variables yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`clear()` is not called for you, but there is no need to. The destructor will take care of cleanup and release the memory used by the map internally.

You should only clear the map if you expect that other global objects which will be destructed upon exiting `main` depend on fact that the map is empty (which looks like a bad idea, but who knows...)

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually I was asking about initialization of such variables, although I was unaware of the destruction take on the map variable.

Answer (score 0):

The map will be destructed, but not until after main has finished. Invoking `clear()` at the end of `main` or not will only affect your program if `h` is referenced by destructors of other globals (which ought to be in the same translation unit).